# ipfw on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: osx, ipfw

I'm trying to setup local transparent proxy with `ipfw` and `squid` and ran into some problems. I have a single rule `00100 fwd 127.0.0.1,3128 log tcp from any to any dst-port 80` but it either gets into infinite loop or doesn't work for some other reason. There's a `ipfw: 100 Forward to 127.0.0.1:3128 TCP 172.17.244.135:56788 74.125.232.0:80 out via en0` message in `system.log` when I `curl` something but `nc` listening on port 3128 doesn't receive anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If `squid` is running on the same machine you will have an infinite loop I guess as the request from squid will trigger `from any to any dst-port 80` again. I don't think you would be able to devise a rule that ignores traffic from specific programs, unless you start using multiple routing tables (fib's in FreeBSD parlance).

I suggest you look at configuring a proxy in your software by setting environment variables like `HTTP_PROXY` for `curl`, `wget`, `fetch`, etc. and configuring the proxy in your browser.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like another adapter is needed for this to work. So I'm sticking with regular (non-transparent) proxy for the time being.

Comment: Actually, `squid` sends everything to port 8080 of upstream proxy, so it should be possible to avoid loops without extra interfaces.